# Can we read an object serialized in .NET in a linux machine?

Tags: c#, java, .net, serialization

I need to transfer some files written in serialized form as files in a windows machine (C#.NET serialization) to a linux machine. How can I achieve this? I need to use perl/Java/bash in linux side preferably.

Edit: To be clearer, files are text files.. but binary serialized in .NET. In linux side, I need to use Perl/Java/Bash to de-serialize and read these files. I have the constraint that the .NET side code cannot be touched.. Anything I do has to be on the linux side..

Thanks,

Comment: You question is not very clear; what kind of files? What kind of data?  You need to use perl/java/bash to do what?

Comment: This isn't really clearer... which kind of serialization are you using ? binary ? XML ?

Comment: Serialize it with java and deserialize it with java, what's the problem with this?

Comment: Oh sorry... it's binary serialization.. my bad

Comment: @Saeed - I have the constraint that the .NET side code cannot be touched.. Anything I do has to be on the linux side..

Comment: Steel you can serialize it with .net (in windows), and then serialize it in your own way, and then deserialize it in linux. means write a c# wrapper for it, to deserialize it.

Comment: hmm.. I am new to this... sorry.. can you explain a bit in the answers? Or point me to an example please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can deserialise .NET-serialised data on Linux if you have a .NET CLI implementation, such as [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com) or [DotGNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/dotgnu). This way you would be able to write a C# wrapper to handle the deserialisation then, as Brian stated above, reserialise using XML if you want to use the data in a non .NET application.

For .NET, the necessary namespaces and classes are:

BinaryFormatter and FileStream classes:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
System.IO.FileStream
```

To deserialise, create an instance of the BinaryFormatter and FileStream classes, loading the serialised data into the FileStream. Then call Deserialize on the BinaryFormatter and cast into the necessary data type (I've called it TheClass below):

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
FileStream file = File.OpenRead(@"InsertFileName");
TheClass classInstance = (TheClass)formatter.Deserialize(file);
file.Close();
```

XML serialisation using raw XML or SOAP is more interoperable with non .NET apps. SOAP serialisation is available using the SoapFormatter class:

```
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter
```

Serialisation is performed by creating FileStream and SoapFormatter instances and calling the Soapformatter Serialize method. To serialise the classInstance example above:

```
FileStream file = File.Create(@"InsertFileName");
SoapFormatter formatter = new SoapFormatter();
formatter.Serialize(file, classInstance);
file.Close();
```

Raw XML serialisation is highly customisable but works slightly differently. The XMLSerializer class is used for this purpose:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer
```

To serialize TheClass using XML serialisation, you will need instances of XmlSerializer and StreamWriter (in System.IO):

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TheClass));
StreamWriter xmlFile = new StreamWriter(@"InsertFileName");
serializer.Serialize(xmlFile, classInstance);
xmlFile.Close();
```

Once in XML, either raw or SOAP, other languages such as Java should have little difficulty reading them. For more info on XML serialisation, see [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.aspx) on MSDN.

To work with .NET on Linux, the Mono Project have created an IDE called MonoDevelop which works in a similar way to Visual Studio on Windows.

I hope this infornmation is useful!

Comment: Oh - forgot to mention that you will need to create an implementation of TheClass in both the C# wrapper and in the target language. If TheClass is contained in a DLL on Windows, this can be used with Mono or DotGNU on Linux thus simplifying this process within the C# wrapper. Note, however, that this will not work for the target language - an implementation will need to be built for that.

Comment: Thanks Hazel, I think we could try this. Have you used Mono though? How easy is it to set up and run? Is it very stable?

Comment: In my experience, Mono is pretty easy to setup and run.  It took me (having no clue what I was doing and never having used Mono) less than a day to both setup Mono and port an existing Winforms project to Mono so that it would compile and run.  It had awful performance (Mono + Windows Forms = Pain), but I doubt you'll have the same issues.  I was on OSX, but that I doubt there's much difference in difficulty between that and Linux setup.

Comment: Your welcome! Yes - I agree, Mono is easy to set up and run. As far as I know, it comes pre-installed on Ubuntu, and can be easily installed on SUSE, Debian, Fedora and others. I'm not certain about stability, but in my experience it has worked with very few problems.

Answer (score 2):

Even though you can't touch the .Net code, you could probably still solve this problem by writing a simple .Net program which takes as input a serialized object and gives as output a reserialized object (using a serialization that is easier to read, such as XML).  If that is not practical, you will be experiencing pain.  I'm not aware of a Linux wrapper that can read windows .Net Binary Serialized files, though it is possible that Mono knows how to do it.

If you want to do it yourself, you may find Lluis Sanchez Gual's [page](http://primates.ximian.com/~lluis/dist/binary_serialization_format.htm) to be a helpful start at documenting how it works, though it's an old page.

Comment: good idea, wrap it and the serialize in a format you know will work

Comment: Thanks Brian, this is what we were doing... converting it to XML serialization and reading with Java on the other side. But there are concerns over the windows side being overloaded (it is a high-load server)

Answer (score 1):

Serialization contains enough information to pull up the corresponding objects and populate them with date.

For *simple* objects you can emulate the deserialization process but there is nothing to help you do so.  You need to implement everything yourself.